# PHP: How to handle with SQL return values?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

after I fixed my problems and put each value into her own SQL field I want to process the values I get from my database.

With this statement `SELECT price, price_old, link, shop FROM wp_all_import WHERE pid = 8385` I get the following values:

**Image**
[image]

It is very important that the values in each row stay together!
So e.g. the price 5, price_old, 10, link http://5-10.de and shop 7952 MUST stay together when I process with the values in PHP.

My question now is, how can I handle with the data I get returned in PHP?
Does I get a two-dimensional array? - What do I get back?

My PHP Code:

```
$values = $database->query("SELECT `price`, `price_old`, `link`, `shop` FROM `wp_all_import` WHERE pid = '$pid'");
```

Greetings and Thank You!

Comment: $values will be a `resultset`, and you `fetch` each row from that to an array or to an object.... there's literally thousands of tutorials describing this on the interwebz, and the PHP Docs are also good for providing examples

Comment: For shop 7952 which link do you want returned?Does it matter?

Comment: Of course it matters!
Every row is one unique. So every row must stay together. But how can I now get the values for each row?

Comment: What do you mean "stay together"?  Can you give examples of what you want and do not want?

Comment: I already fixed it by fetching :D - Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

You need aggregate

```
SELECT SUM(price), SUM(price_old), GROUP_CONCAT(link), shop FROM wp_all_import WHERE pid = 8385
GROUP BY shop
```

If you don`t care about returning all links just remove GROUP_CONCAT an it will return a link at random or maybe remove link altogether.